# How do we emulate touch events in Safari Responsive Design Mode?

Tags: responsive-design, safari, web-inspector, dom-events, safari-web-inspector

Chromium has this feature Device Mode, and interaction is how it would be on a touch device.

I've tried Safari's Responsive Design Mode, but I don't see a way to emulate touch (without pointer events). It just behaves like I'm using a mouse, but I'd like for it to behave like I'm touching the screen on a mobile device (like in Chrome's inspector).

Comment: Apple is so behind in so much of this stuff.

Answer (score 16):

You can install Apple xCode. After installation, search Simulator through Spotlight.

[image: Search Simulator through Spotlight]

With Simulator you can open Safari and simulate yours websites with touch control.

[image: iPhone 5 with iOS 10.1]

[image: Stackoverflow opened through Simulator]

Comment: While this is definitely usable, I don't think it's a valid way to test web games for example, because of the drastic performance decrease. There should be a built-in feature for this like Chrome has.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. When using Safari on desktop in responsive mode your mouse will only generate mouse events.

Maybe a better solution for your use case than using the Simulator is to use Chrome desktop. When using the dev tools in device mode it will emulate tap events.

Comment: True, but then it is hard to test in actual Safari without an actual mobile device. Though, testing in an actual mobile device is probably the most accurate way to test.

Comment: I'm amazed if that's still the case - but hmm a workaround for a javascript snippet would be easy for the touchstart/end - although the behavior of the "touchmove" compared to "mousemove" introduces more complexity. After a reflection - I guess the iPhone-simulator is optimal in many ways

Comment: Safari has different support and behaves differently sometimes than Chrome - so I feel like this is a bad answer

Comment: I guess it depend on the use case. I haven't seen any differences for touch start/end/move events. Do you have any info on those differences?